Kibana is unable to connect to Elasticsearch
Kibana is unable to connect to Elasticsearch 7.1.5
We get the following error sometimes on the Kibana dashboard console, but sometimes it just works fine
http://<myip>:5602/app/dev_tools/#/console
{"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"Not Found"}

Its not clear how we should go about debugging this issue

can you share the kibana and elasticsearch logs? is there any error in the log file?
